# Apache Cordova build command does nothing

Tags: cordova

So I installed apache cordova via npm install and was able to generate a project. I then added the platform for IOS. I go into the platforms/ios/ and open the project and can run it just fine.

Now I go back to the project root and change whats in the www folder. I go back to the command line and run cordova build and I just get a prompt back

```
~/Development/Work/PickApp
❯ cordova build

~/Development/Work/PickApp
❯
```

If I run the command to remove the platform and add it back I see my changes. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Haven't you updated to node.js v5 recently? It seems to have that kind of problems with cordova.

Comment: Yes I am running node version 5. Is there a bug tracker somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You added the platform for IOS,

So use a Apple MacBook Laptop Because If it is not IOS platfrom it won't work.